# Como formatar células em excel através de php?

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, csv

Tenho um código em php que recupera dados numa base de dados e gera um arquivo CSV.

O cliente abre esse CSV em excel para visualizar os dados. Até aqui tudo bem.

A demanda do cliente é que ele quer abrir o arquivo em excel e ele quer ter também algumas células pré-formatadas como se fosse o cabeçalho do documento - veja exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha pergunta é como que fazemos isso isso? A formatação da célula deve estar contida dentro do CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente usar tag html dentro dos campos como por exemplo:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h1>Titulo</h1></td>
    <td><strong>Titulo</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```